# Elongated word check in sentence

Tags: python, regex, file, sentence

I want to check in a sentence if there are elongated words. For example, soooo, toooo, thaaatttt, etc. Now I dont know what the user might type because I have a list of sentences which may or may not have elongated words. How do I check that in python. I am new to python.

Comment: It seems to me you should be looking for any word containing the same letter at least three times in a row. I am not aware of any actual English words which do this.

Comment: Step # 1 is to define an elongated word, whether by reference to a known dictionary or by some rule such as @HughBothwell proposed.

Comment: @HughBothwell: KKK and WWW are the only "elongated" words [found in `/etc/share/dict/words`](https://gist.github.com/7622403)

Comment: @HughBothwell: [`nltk.corpus.brown.words()`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html#module-nltk.corpus) (the [Brown Corpus](http://icame.uib.no/brown/bcm.html)) includes some of elongated words such as: wooooosh, pfffted, Aaawww, unnnt, Sssshoo, bannnnnng.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re
s1 = "This has no long words"
s2 = "This has oooone long word"

def has_long(sentence):
    elong = re.compile("([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}")
    return bool(elong.search(sentence))


print has_long(s1)
False
print has_long(s2)
True
```

Comment: The `True if X else False` pattern is usually written `bool(X)`.

Comment: thanks that's tidier! updated

Comment: note: `[a-zA-Z]` fails for mixed case: `'Sssshoo'`

Answer (score 3):

@HughBothwell had a good idea.  As far as I know, there is not a single English word that has the same letter repeat three consecutive times.  So, you can search for words that do this:

```
>>> from re import search
>>> mystr = "word word soooo word tooo thaaatttt word"
>>> [x for x in mystr.split() if search(r'(?i)[a-z]\1\1+', x)]
['soooo,', 'tooo', 'thaaatttt']
>>>
```

Any you find will be elongated words.

Comment: `\w` picks up numbers such as `'8888'`. It doesn't support non-ascii letters such as `'ёёё'` so you could replace it with [`r'(?i)[a-z]\1\1+'`](https://gist.github.com/7622403)

Comment: note: the flag `(?i)` takes care of it. And it also works for mixed case such as `'Sssshoo'` i.e., `A-Z` is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can make a list of every elongated word logically possible. Then loop through the words in the sentence then the words in the list to find elongated words.

```
sentence = "Hoow arre you doing?"
elongated = ["hoow",'arre','youu','yoou','meee'] #You will need to have a much larger list
for word in sentence:
    word = word.lower()
    for e_word in elongated:
        if e_word == word:
            print "Found an elongated word!"
```

If you wanted to do what Hugh Bothwell said, then:

```
sentence = "Hooow arrre you doooing?"
elongations = ["aaa","ooo","rrr","bbb","ccc"]#continue for all the letters 
for word in sentence:
    for x in elongations:
        if x in word.lower():
            print '"'+word+'" is an elongated word'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a reference of valid English words available. On *NIX systems, you could use `/etc/share/dict/words` or `/usr/share/dict/words` or equivalent and store all the words into a `set` object.

Then, you'll want to check, for every word in a sentence,

1. That the word is not itself a valid word (i.e., `word not in all_words`); and
2. That, when you shorten all consecutive sequences to one or two letters, the new word is a valid word.

Here's one way you might try to extract all of the possibilities:

```
import re
import itertools

regex = re.compile(r'\w\1\1')

all_words = set(get_all_words())

def without_elongations(word):
    while re.search(regex, word) is not None:
        replacing_with_one_letter = re.sub(regex, r'\1', word, 1)
        replacing_with_two_letters = re.sub(regex, r'\1\1', word, 1)
        return list(itertools.chain(
            without_elongations(replacing_with_one_letter),
            without_elongations(replacing_with_two_letters),
        ))

for word in sentence.split():
    if word not in all_words:
        if any(map(lambda w: w in all_words, without_elongations(word)):
            print('%(word) is elongated', { 'word': word })
```